# install tensorflow for gpu without conda

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any way to run TensorFlow on the GPU without using anaconda? Most of the resources that I found online installed TensorFlow using anaconda. It runs fine on CPU, but I am trying to get it running on my NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: Hi @chiru, For using gpu with tensorflow you have to download and install respective versions of Cuda Toolkit and cudaDNN manually from Nvidia, and then have to set path variables for your systems. Thank You.